# setting default endpoint for `polkadot-js/apps` explorer

Tags: polkadot-js, apps

I'm running a `polkadot-js/apps` instance here with the following command:

```sh
docker run -it --name polkadot-ui -e WS_URL=<NODE_URL> -p 80:80 jacogr/polkadot-js-apps:latest
```

The web UI is being served and the browser can load it. But the app tries to connect to `ws://127.0.0.1:9944` instead of the provided `<NODE_URL>`.

[This](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/faa6b3a205ad5030d9d7b67e806426996e4b1580/packages/apps/src/initSettings.ts#L54) seems to be the place where the URL is resolved.

There are some interaction with the packages `@polkadot/apps-config` and `@polkadot/ui-settings` (which is in another repo).

How can I set the default endpoint for the websocket/RPC url on the frontend?